# Ajax callback function to populate hierarchy data in bootstrap treeview

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, bootstrap-treeview

I am using bootstrap treeview to populate hierarchy member data.
https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

The sample of json data to populate the treeview:

```
var json = '[' +
                '{' +
                    '"text": "Parent 1",' +
                    '"nodes": [' +
                        '{' +
                            '"text": "Child 1",' +
                            '"nodes": [' +
                                '{' +
                                    '"text": "Grandchild 1"' +
                                '},' +
                                '{' +
                                    '"text": "Grandchild 2"' +
                                '}' +
                            ']' +
                        '},' +
                        '{' +
                            '"text": "Child 2"' +
                        '}' +
                    ']' +
                '},' +
                '{' +
                    '"text": "Parent 2"' +
                '},' +
                '{' +
                    '"text": "Parent 3"' +
                '},' +
                '{' +
                    '"text": "Parent 4"' +
                '},' +
                '{' +
                    '"text": "Parent 5"' +
                '}' +
            ']';
```

I have a ajax function, which it will get the direct down-line by passing memberID.

```
function getTree2(mid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../DataServices/ws_member.asmx/GetDirectDownlineByMemberID",
            data: "{'memberID':'" + mid + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                var str = '';
                var result = JSON.parse(response.d)
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    str += '"text": "' + result[i].Name + '",' +
                          '"nodes": [' +
                         '{';

                    str += getTree2(result[i].ID);

                    str += '}' +
                     ']';
                }
                str += '}' +
                   ']';

                return str;
            },
            dataType: "json"
        });   
    }
```

but the following line cannot return any string.

```
str += getTree2(result[i].ID);
```

How do i loop the function getTree2 in ajax callback to return string?

Answer (score 0):

As Ajax call will be processed in an async thread so if you want to take back the return string, you should pass a callback thru

```
function getTree2(mid, callback)
```

Then in line #23:

```
    return callback(str);
```

So to add the new string:

```
getTree2(result[i].ID, function(newStr) { 
    str += newStr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right format that should pass to the treeview isn't what you get back from the Ajax call you should parse the json object like the following example:

```
let invalid = '{ "bank": "CityBank", "sum": "500" }, { "bank": "WPBank", "sum": "700" }';
let valid = JSON.parse("[" + invalid + "]");
```

Now you can pass the valid variable to the treeView without any problems.

It all about to add square brackets notation to JSON object